# File.Exists always returns false

Tags: c#

My app is a 32 bit .Net VS 2017 app. File.Exists always returns false in my app. Either running in VS, deployed locally, or as admin. Running on a Windows 10 64 bit system. Paths are good because the File.Copy works (but always since File.Exist isn't working. I don't want File.Copy to run unless file doesn't exist. Maybe suggestions for a workaround if I can't get it to work? File permissions shouldn't be a problem since the file is in the Documents folder. Maybe a better SpecialFolder to use than MyDocuments? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance. Code below.

```
// Class variables

public static string appPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + 
"\\Lottery Analyzer Expert International";  
public static string dbPath = appPath + "\\database\\";
public static string dbFile = "Histories.sqlite";

// Class method

public void copyInputFiles_db()
{    
    string dest = dbPath + dbFile;
    string src = Application.StartupPath + "\\database\\" + dbFile;

    if (!File.Exists(dest)) { }
    {
        File.Copy(src, dest, true);  // if input files not found in appPath copy from install folder

        bool do_download = true;
        DialogResult dialogResult2 = MessageBox.Show(
            "The history database was copied from the application's startup to it's working dirctory. This happens when first running " + 
            "the application or the history file is missing. Would you like to update that file from the web?", 
            "Download file?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (dialogResult2 == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            do_download = true;
        }
        else if (dialogResult2 == DialogResult.No)
        {
            do_download = false;
        }

        if (do_download)
            downloadAllTheHistoryFIles_db();
    }
    printTextFiles();
}
```

Comment: Always use `Path.Combine` to combine directory and file names, newer a + operator. Use the debugger to find the value of the path at the time where the call fails.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You know that the code below the `if` is always executed?

```
if (!File.Exists(dest)) { } // << the { } is the IF scope   
{    // <- this is a new scope also, but not part of the if..

    File.Copy(src, dest, true);  
    bool do_download = true;
    // *SNIP*

}
```

Remove the `{ }` behind the `if`

Comment: That was it !!! wow what a bad bug !!! Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: I have to wait a few minutes before I can accept your answer.